# Make value of a previous few roles to be the value of the row if the row is not nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the one below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan]*99,columns = ['col1'])

df.loc[23] = 70
df.loc[35] = 50
df.loc[90] = 81
df.loc[98] = 3
```

How can I make the value of a new column (col2) to be the value of the previous few (x) rows of the df col1 to become the value of the rows with value? For example, if x = 4, making row 20-23 to be 70, row 32-35 to be 50, row 87-90 to be 81 and row 95-98 to be 3?

Thanks!

Comment: You are right! I have revised the question. Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If another values are missing, use back filling with limit parameter:

```
df1 = df.bfill(limit=3)
print (df1.tail(15))

    col1
84   NaN
85   NaN
86   NaN
87  81.0
88  81.0
89  81.0
90  81.0
91   NaN
92   NaN
93   NaN
94   NaN
95   3.0
96   3.0
97   3.0
98   3.0
```

Comment: @MATTHEW - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)